# MUI Icons module augmentation for color overrides

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I'm having custom colors in my MUI theme.
Everything is in Typescript.

I'm overriding color props from MUI with module augmentation. No issue whatsoever with any of the basic MUI components, but the color override is still shown as an error when I'm trying to do the same thing with icons (imported from @mui/icons-material).

How should I proceed to spread the override to all of MUI Icons components?

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Palette {
        gold: Palette['primary'];
    }

    interface PaletteOptions {
        gold?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    }
}

// Works fine
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
        gold: true;
    }
}

// Does not work
declare module '@mui/icons-material' {
    interface CommonPropsColorOverrides {
        gold: true;
    }
}

// ...
// createTheme() options and colors
```